# How to organize different Node.js services?

Tags: node.js

This question does not necessarily pertain to the organization of Node project structure, and more of how to represent separate, logical services. Within our team, we have requirements to create and support several services (i.e., a set of API endpoints). These services aren't directly related, so my initial reaction is they should be separate projects with separate code bases running in separate Node (or Express) servers. I'm wondering if this approach would complicate deployment and management. The alternative would be to have a single "entry point" (i.e., a single Node server) that delegates to the respective services depending on which context root or URL is seen. I'm curious which approach seems more logical and how people are handling these "microservices" in the wild now?

Comment: I was tempted to flag this as primarily opinion-based, but then I got curious...

Comment: Hi Robert, I can understand how it may seem opinion based, but I'm looking more for best practices (which is arguably still opinion based) to avoid any egregious pitfalls in up-front design.

Comment: Yup, that's why I changed my mind.:-)

Answer (score 0):

> These services aren't directly related

These services should be separate projects/repos with distinct entry points.

> I'm wondering if this approach would complicate deployment and management.

Yes, absolutely. I have several NodeJS JSON APIs in production and for each, I have 2-3 environments (canary, staging, production). When you get to about 3 production services in the wild, things can get unwieldy without some discipline.

You can manage this with documentation (via wiki or in repo) about each service and their environments as well as any other dependencies (services that this service depends on).

This also helps with emergencies where a service is slow or not responding. Sometimes, the service itself is fine but a service's dependency could be down. For example, the github API may be a dependency...it goes down.

> The alternative would be to have a single "entry point" (i.e., a single Node server) that delegates to the respective services depending on which context root or URL is seen.

In some cases, you may have to *also* build a "gateway" service which consumes your other single-purpose services. One reason to do this is to support authentication and authorization (i.e. OAuth).

In other words, you may need multiple micro-services and a gateway service.